# App engine urlfetch issue

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urlfetch

Im trying to request https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?url=[http://www.my-website.dk/]&key=[my-key] using urlfetch from app engine but it's not working.

When I access it and hardcode my-url into the request like this: https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?url=http://www.my-website.dk/&key=[my-key] it's working fine, but when I use urlfetch.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?url=%s&key=[my-key]", "http://www.my-website.dk") it's not working, I have also tried:

```
page_content = urlfetch.fetch(
        url="https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed",
        payload=params,
        method=urlfetch.GET
      )
```

and then serving the parameters in the payload like this:

```
params = urllib.urlencode({
        "url": page.link,
        "key": "[my-key]"
      })
```

but the result is the same, it's not working and the service gives me HTTP status code 400. I also tried adding urlfetch.fetch(u("http://...", page.link) but the result is the same.

I edited the code based on the reply from systempuntoout incase any one should run into the same problem:

```
params = urllib.urlencode({
        "url": page.link,
        "key": "AIzaSyAFpm6W_OmjQl33JC98mAPkvrdGmrR0i4Y"
      })

      page_content = urlfetch.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?%s" % params)
```

Comment: You're passing two arguments to fetch. I think that , wants to be a %

Comment: Please be more specific than "it's not working" - and include your actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the `urlfetch` call has an error because you are passing two parameters to the function.
You should use the `%` between the two strings to pass just one url parameter to the function.

```
urlfetch.fetch("https://www.goo..e/v1/runPagespeed?url=%s&key=[my-key]" %
                                               "http://www.my-website.dk")
```

Then, have you tried to [urlencode](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) the second url?

```
import urllib
your_url = {'url': 'http://www.my-website.dk/&key=[my-key]'}
urlfetch.fetch("https://www.g../v1/runPagespeed?%s" % urllib.urlencode(your_url))
```

Answer (score 0):

payload is only applicable for POST/PUT requests. For GET, your params need to be part of the URL